# i want to be able yo open another url inside my react web app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-redux

i have created a react app where user can login and have account my question here i want to add a feature in my app and it is that user can open YouTube ,Facebook or search google inside my web app i make some searches but i didn't get an answer so is this possible and how it can be done

these are some of the features i have done but i want to do the feature i told you about later it is very important step in my app

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={SignUp} />
          <PrivateRouter path='/user-profile' component={UserProfile} />
          <PrivateRouter path='/time-line' component={UserTimline} />
          <PrivateRouter path='/users-list' component={UsersPage} />
          <PrivateRouter path='/update-profile' component={UpdateProfilePic} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use iframe in react app:**

This package does what you want it to do:
[react-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-iframe)

Simple React component for including an iframed page.

```
import Iframe from 'react-iframe'
<Iframe url="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xDMP3i36naA"
        width="450px"
        height="450px"
        id="myId"
        className="myClassname"
        display="initial"
        position="relative"/>
```